# Change the log destination for node.js running on GCE

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am using rc.local to start my node script on start with:

```
node .> "/log_file_$(date +"%H:%M:%S_%m_%d_%Y").txt"
```

It works fine - but now once the log grows in size - I need to create a new log on a server every 12/24 hours; without restarting the server.

Is there any simple way to change the node app output destination?

I would prefer not to use any library for that, because I need to log all the messages including errors, warns, not only console.log.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options, I'll offer two:

#### 1. Stackdriver

Stream your logs to [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/), which is part of Google Cloud, and don't store them on your server at all. In your node.js application, you can can setup Winston and use [the Winston transport for Stackdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston). Then you can analyze and query them there, and don't need to worry about storage running out.

#### 2. `logrotate`

If you want to deal with this manually, you can configure [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/logrotate.8.html). It will gzip older logs so that they consume less disk space. This is a sort of older, "pre-cloud" way of doing things.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing those solutions Travis!
I haven't heared about stackdriver - so that's a good direction.
However - we have 2 systems: one on GCP, and one that runs in client'

Comment: You don't need to run inside of GCP to stream to Stackdriver. Create a service account with the `logWriter` permission, and you can install the agent or the winston transport anywhere and authenticate with that service account.